# Can the monolingual Transformers models be used for another languages in NLP tasks?

Tags: python, nlp, huggingface-transformers, sentence-transformers

I need to fine-tune the Sentence Transformer model for Tr language. I realized that some pre-trained models are giving similar results in different languages.

- So, Can we use it to fine-tune ST pre-trained model in English, for
  other languages?
- Can we say that the English model can be used in another
  language in Sentence Embeddings(Sentence Transformer)?

I will be glad if you can help.

Comment: Are you planning to finetune the model?

Comment: Actually, I planning to finetune any model or If its logically, I aim to convert monolingual model to multilingual model in sentence transformer

Comment: Well, you can always do that, but the question is whether it is efficient. In general, you can say that monolingual models can be finetuned to other languages much faster if the target language belongs to the same language family. Can't you just use a multilingual model right away?